# error "string literal contains an unescaped line break" on append DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wrote this code to append @Html.DropDownList to div.

```
var markup = '<div class="col-md-2">@Html.DropDownList("Contact[" + i.ToString() + "].Contact_ContactTypeID", (SelectList)(ViewData["TelContactTypelist"]),  new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })</div>';
            $(".box").append(markup);
```

But in "Inspect Element" gives the following error:
SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

My dropdown in the Inspector :

```
<select id="Contact_0__Contact_ContactTypeID" name="Contact[0].Contact_ContactTypeID">
<option value="">select....</option>
<option value="38">10101010</option>
<option value="30">11111111</option>
<option value="31">2222222</option>
<option value="32">3333333</option>
</select>
```

where is the problem from?

Comment: What is the value of `i` .  If it's have `'` you need to escape that like `It\'s string`.

Comment: @Shree : i is index...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by reinitialize chosen drop down

Answer (score 0):

edit this code syntax

```
'<div class="col-md-2">@Html.DropDownList("Contact[" + i.ToString() + "].Contact_ContactTypeID", (SelectList)(ViewData["TelContactTypelist"]),  new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })</div>'
```

**TO** :

```
'<div class="col-md-2">@Html.DropDownList("Contact["' + i.ToString() + '"].Contact_ContactTypeID", (SelectList)(ViewData["TelContactTypelist"]),  new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })</div>'
```